# java.lang.illegalstateexception database not open android

Tags: android, sqlite

When I am trying to insert to data base log cat shows an error like `java.lang.illegalstateexception database not open android.`

But I have opened the db using

```
   db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

The error is not occurring frequently.Anybody know the reason for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
  if (!db.isOpen()) {
       db = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
     }
```

Comment: I tried this but instead of getApplicationContext() I have added SQLiteDatabase.How will get applicationcontext in a class extended from SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: so contructor of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` takes one parameter `Context context` so `context.openOrCreateDatabase()` ...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
DatabaseHelper dataHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    public DbManager openDB() throws SQLException {

    mDb = dataHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

and call this method where your re writing your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database

            File dbFile = _myContext.getDatabasePath( DB_PATH + DB_NAME ); 
            _myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.toString(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

            return _myDataBase;
        }//end of openDataBase() method
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you are opening an opened Database. close your database every time your work is done.